# Python: Sum the Values by the Key in Json Data for Each Country

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm having issues to sum the values by the key for each country. The json data includes all the countries and each country has all the dates and each date has case numbers. The data looks like the following:

```
{
  "Afghanistan": [
    {
      "date": "2020-1-22",
      "confirmed": 0,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 0
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-23",
      "confirmed": 0,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 0
    },
   ...
   ...
  "Albania":
   ...
   ...
}
```

I'm trying to show it as something like below (country and total confirmed cases for the country):

Afghanistan
###

Albania
###

Below are the codes that I've tried, but the results doesn't seem to be correct.

```
     contents = requests.get('https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json').json()
        for country in contents:
            print(country)
            data = contents[country]

            idx = 0
            confirmed_total = 0
            for each_day in data:
                confirmed_total += data[idx]['confirmed']
                idx += 1
            print(confirmed_total)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected output basd on your sample input?

Comment: @MayankPorwal Hi, I'm trying to get total confirmed cases number for each country. I'm not worried about the output format now, just trying to get the correct total confirmed cases number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could help:

You can iterate over the dictionary for each key(which is a country) and simultaneously iterate over its value(which is a list of dicts) to find the key(which is confirmed) and sum it.

```
In [303]: d = { 
     ...:   "Afghanistan": [ 
     ...:     { 
     ...:       "date": "2020-1-22", 
     ...:       "confirmed": 10, 
     ...:       "deaths": 0, 
     ...:       "recovered": 0 
     ...:     }, 
     ...:     { 
     ...:       "date": "2020-1-23", 
     ...:       "confirmed": 9, 
     ...:       "deaths": 0, 
     ...:       "recovered": 0 
     ...:     } 
     ...:    ] } 
     ...:      

In [305]: for key, value in d.items(): 
     ...:     sum = 0 
     ...:     for element in value: 
     ...:         sum = sum + element['confirmed'] 
     ...:     print('{}:{}'.format(key, sum)) 
     ...:      

Afghanistan:19
```

Comment: Thank you! Silly me. It turns out your result is the same as mine, and I noticed that confirmed cases for each day is cumulated cases number, not the new cases for the day. It wouldn't make sense to add all days up any more... Thanks for your easier approach anyway!